# Parametric form of Parabola

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Recently I was going through co-ordinate geometry. While studying about parabola I encountered something called "parameteric coordinates". In my textbook some parameteric coordinates were given ***[y²=4ax : (at², 2at)]*** for specific equations of parabola, but nothing related to how these coordinates are defined was there.

Searched a lot but cant find anything convincing, one of many posts said it's done by defining x and y in terms of an other variable where **x(t)=t** itself and **y(t)=a*x(t)² => y=at²** *from standard eqn of parabola*.

Well, it does not make any sense as *(t,at²)* isn't any parameteric coordinate.

I am really confused ***(to the extent where I can no longer differentiate between maths and biology)*** Please someone help me.

I need an elaborate answer ASAP. *(I am no mathemagician please be clear and don't use heavy terminology)*

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've added an answer but realise I've made some assumptions about exactly what your question is. My main suggestion would be to use something like geogebra or desmos and play around with the sort of curves you can get.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave for a parabola, $t$ is the parameter. It looks like you have the right understanding of how parametric coordinates work (ie each point on a curve is given by two functions of a parameter; in your parabola example, if you put in, say, $t=3$, you get the point $(9a,6a)$). However, I don't think a parabola is the best example of why these can be helpful, even among conics.

Let's start with a circle with radius $r$ centred at $(0,0)$. The Cartesian equation for this is $x^2+y^2=r^2$. But this is an implicit formula; you have to do some calculation to get $y$ in terms of $x$. OK; rearrange and we get
$$y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
...and plotting this, we get a *semicircular* arc. In fact, for every $-r<x<r$, we need *two* corresponding $y$ values; we can write this as
$$y=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
but it doesn't change the fact that we can't write $y$ as a function of $x$ (technically, a function needs to just have one output for a given input).

Here's the parametric form for the same circle:
$$x=r\cos{t},\quad y=r\sin{t}$$

Hopefully you can see why this works. Now, for every value of $t$, we get exactly one point on the circle, which makes this form far easier to work with (in certain applications - eg physics of circular motion; in fact, one of the common uses for parametric coordinates is in modelling motion, where the parameter is often time).

Now, in this case, $t$ corresponds exactly to the angle the line joining the point on the circle to $O$ makes with the positive $x$-axis; but this isn't a necessary property of the parameterisation. We could just as well say
$$x=r\cos{2t+5},\quad y=r\sin{2t+5}$$
and get the same circle.

Similarly, it's easy to parameterise an ellipse:
$$x=a\cos{t},\quad y=b\sin{t}$$

(just scaling the circle) or a hyperbola:
$$x=a\cosh{t},\quad y=b\sinh{t}$$

The similarities between these forms are another reason it can be useful to use parametric coordinates for conics (and other curves).

In case you're not familiar with $\cosh$ and $\sinh$, another form for the hyperbola is
$$x=a\sec{t},\quad y=b\tan{t}$$

Another advantage of parametric coordinates is it is relatively easy to shift and rotate curves by using matrix transformations (not every ellipse has axes parallel to the coordinate axes, after all).

I hope that's useful - let me know if anything isn't clear!

Comment: Ok but could please explain how parameteric coordinates for parabola are derived.

Comment: Like for a circle it can be derived by simply using trigonometry. I need to know how did someone come up with the result that coordinates of parabola (say, y²=4ax) be written as (at²,2at).

Comment: "How did someone come up with it" is a hard question to answer. Why it works is that from the parametric form, $y^2 = 4a^2 t^2$ and $4ax=4a^2 t^2$. As in the above answer, the parameterisation is not unique - you could simply have $y=u$ and $x=\frac{u^2}{4a}$. But the form you had is more informative - it tells you something about the scaling of that parabola as you change the constant $a$.

Comment: By the way, the title of your question mentions conics. If you're only interested in the parabola you might want to edit that.